# Adding Authentication Headers to NetworkImageView in Volley

Tags: android, authentication, android-volley, networkimageview

I use Volley and NetworkImageView. This has been working great for several projects. However I need to send auth token in headers for my image request right now. What is the best way to do this? In my normal requests I override getHeaders() and put my token in that way. But ImageLoader which is what NetworkImageView uses generates a generic Request, making it hard to add headers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found an easy way of doing this. I have forked Volley to accomplish what I needed. Feel free to use if you need it.

https://github.com/leofirespotter/ubervolley

Also added in here is making a rounded NetworkImageView copied from (http://solutionforandroid.blogspot.com/2013/12/rounded-networkimageview-using-volley.html)

Answer (score 6):

I have come up with a solution. 
In order to use NetworkImageView you need to create an image loader. At this point of the code, just overide the `makeImageRequest()` method of `ImageLoader`, and inside `makeImageRequest()`, overide the `getHeaders()` method of 'ImageRequest' :

```
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Request<Bitmap> makeImageRequest(String requestUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, final String cacheKey) {
            //return super.makeImageRequest(requestUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight, cacheKey);

            return new ImageRequest(requestUrl, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                    onGetImageSuccess(cacheKey, response);
                }
            }, maxWidth, maxHeight,
                    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    onGetImageError(cacheKey, error);
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Authorization", YOUR_TOKEN);
                    return params;
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

This is technically one line of code :)
I have tested this and it works for me.

Comment: `onGetImagesSuccess()` has private access in ImageLoader.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.