# Adding authentication headers to ImageLoader for NetworkImageView picture loading

Tags: android-listview, http-headers, android-volley, basic-authentication, networkimageview

On a listView, in its adapters' getView method, I need to request an image per ListView item in order to load a picture by item thanks to NetworkImageView. The problem is that I need to add authentication header to the request to allow the user the get pictures from server. I've read some solutions which are not possible to put in practice.

- [First solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919737/android-volley-imageloader-how-to-use-basic-http-authorization)
- [Second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568505/adding-authentication-headers-to-networkimageview-in-volley)

  Does someone has faced this issue ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand `which are not possible to put in practice.`. Moreover, post your code and your logcat for more info

Answer (score 2):

I've find out how to set a Basic Authentication header into an ImageLoader. I was misunderstanding the answer on that link [same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17860678/2187228). So credit goes to the real answerer.
Anyway the trick was to add an HurlStack into the **getRequestQueue** method as follows:

```
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
{
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {

        HurlStack stack = new HurlStack() {
            @Override
            public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> headers)
                throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

                String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((GlobalVariables.getInstance().getWS_KEY()+":").getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);

                return super.performRequest(request, headers);
            }
        };
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(),stack);
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

The **RequestQueue** object is placed into a Global class and a singleton pattern is applied, so it means that whenever you request the **RequestQueue**, the authorization header will be in it. Hope it helps !